# Where is the SQL injection vulnerability in given code and how to exploit it using python and sqlite

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I was given this code

```
import sqlite3
     def blorksnork(xorkThorb) :
     snerk = []
     borkbork = sqlite3.connect('MorkDork.db')
     glorb = borkbork.cursor()
     borknork = glorb.execute(xorkThorb)
     for glork in borknork :
         snerk += [str(glork)]
    
     borkbork.commit()
     borkbork.close()
     return snerk

def gorkaplorkplork (shmork) :
     flerb = []
     xork = 'INSERT INTO prisoners (name, lattitude, longitude, resistance) VALUES ("{0}", {1}, {2}, "{3}")'.format(shmork[0], shmork[1], shmork[2], shmork[3])
     xorkTork = xork.split(";")
     for lork in xorkTork :
         flerb += blorksnork(lork)
     return flerb
```

and told to find where the SQL injection vulnerability is and and how to exploit it, I believe the vulnerability comes from the split portion in the second segment but I'm not sure how to take advantage. W are supposed to do this through python and sqlite

Comment: Imagine something like  `shmork[3] = 'a"; delete from prisoners;--'`!

Comment: @KlausD. you're missing the closing `)` after `a"`

Comment: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)  seems apropos.

Comment: so if I wanted to drop the whole table I could do 'shmork[3] = 'a"); drop table prisoners;--''

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the query formatting:

`'INSERT INTO prisoners (name, lattitude, longitude, resistance) VALUES ("{0}", {1}, {2}, "{3}")'.format(shmork[0], shmork[1], shmork[2], shmork[3])`

What you're doing here is inserting arguments into the query using `format`. This doesn't escape the arguments and therefore allows for SQL injection. Let's use a simpler example:

`'INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES ("{0}")'.format(name)`

If the value of `name` is `Bob`, the final value of the query is:

`INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES ("Bob")`

This isn't safe. If, for example, the value of `name` is `Bob"); DROP TABLE example--` (or something similar based on the SQL dialect), the final value of the query is

`INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES ("Bob"); DROP TABLE example;--")`

What this does is inserts `Bob` into the database as normal, but then adds a new query to delete the entire table. Then we use `--` to comment out the rest of the line.

To solve this problem, we have to escape the input. Instead of string formatting, this is how we should create the query:

`db.execute('INSERT INTO example (name) VALUES (?)', [name]);`

This will cause the input to be properly sanitized and will be safe to run.